# Wordpress give non users access to files

Tags: wordpress, file-permissions, chatroom

I'm trying to create a chatroom on my wordpress website. Every time a user sends a message, this message is stored in a log file and other users are able to see the message by reading the log file and displaying it on their end.

I also want to allow other people browsing the website to participate in the chatroom (i.e they don't have to be users/ they don't have to sign in).
However, this is not working and I suspect it's because they cannot read the log file (so the messages are not displayed). I also suspect that they won't be able to write on the log file either.

Is there anyway I could grant them read/write access to the log file and is there any issue in doing so?

Comment: Why log file and not database?

Comment: Is better to use database, but if you still want to use an log file, use PHP to get the file contents.